# Can't generate PDF from html

Tags: javascript, node.js

tried to use several libraries for pdf generation but I catch always one error:

```
Fatal Error: spawn UNKNOWN
```

code, something like is:

```js
  mammoth.convertToHtml({
      path: './backend/common/template.docx'
    })
    .then(function (result) {
      var html = result.value; // The generated HTML

      pdf.create(html).toFile("./backend/common/vvvv.pdf", function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
          callback(err);
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        callback(null, res);
      });

      var messages = result.messages; // Any messages, such as warnings during conversion
      console.log(messages);
    })
    .done();
```

Help please, what is wrong

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read the guidelines as this is a negative vote farm in it's current form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the import

```
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
```

Make sure you have installed the html to pdf converter through node and imported/required the file!